How to implement dynamic access requirements for a route?
I have a route defined in module.routing.yml, and I want to add a UI in the module to let the user configure what types of access to allow:

Oauth2
JWT
Cookie

How do I do that, since routing.yml is a static file?
jsonrpc.routing.yml:
jsonrpc.handler:
  path: '/jsonrpc'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\jsonrpc\Controller\HttpController::resolve'
  methods: [POST, GET, OPTIONS]
  requirements:
    _permission: 'use jsonrpc services'
  options:
    _auth: ['basic_auth', 'oauth2']

I want to override options: _auth depending on the module config, and if cookie auth is enabled, I need to set _csrf_request_header_token: TRUE for the requirements.
Where in the pipeline is the right place to do this kind of adjustment?

You need a RouteSubscriber to the make the adjustments. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones
To trigger a rebuild of the routing table, which includes calling your custom RouteSubscriber, add the following line when submitting the module config:
\Drupal::service('router.builder')->setRebuildNeeded();


Maybe a RouteSubscriber does help you?
namespace Drupal\jsonrpc\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('jsonrpc.handler')) {
      $config = \Drupal::config('jsonrpc.settings');
      $auth_methods = $config->get('auth_methods') ?: ['basic_auth', 'oauth2'];

      $route->setOption('_auth', $auth_methods);

      if (in_array('cookie', $auth_methods)) {
        $route->setRequirement('_csrf_request_header_token', 'TRUE');
      }
    }
  }
}

Register the event subscriber in your module’s services file, jsonrpc.services.yml:
services:
  jsonrpc.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\jsonrpc\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }

